# Windows store app c# crashed using bing map sdk with route

Tags: c#

I've been struggling for several days with an error in windows.ui.xaml.dll when I use the bing-map SDK in my windows store app. The error only occurs when there is a route shown from A to B on the map and the current location is updated on the map every second. The error hasn't occurred yet when the route is not shown.

When I debug the dump file, I get the following error:

> **The thread tried to to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not     have the appropriate access**
>   errorcode: 0xC0000005 access violation

call stack:

> Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!SolidColorBrushClone::SetValue()    Unknown
>       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CDependencyObject::UpdateEffectiveValue()   Unknown
>       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CAnimation::DoAnimationValueOperation() Unknown
>       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CAnimation::UpdateAnimation()   Unknown
>       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CTimeline::ComputeStateImpl()   Unknown
>       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CTimeline::ComputeState()   Unknown
>       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CStoryboard::ComputeStateImpl() Unknown
>       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CHardwareCompositor::TickIndependentAnimations()    Unknown
>       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CompositorScheduler::RenderThreadFrame()    Unknown
>       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CompositorScheduler::RenderThreadMain(void) Unknown
>       Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!CompositorScheduler::RenderThreadMainStatic(unsigned char *)    Unknown
>       kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
>       ntdll.dll!_*RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
>       ntdll.dll!*_RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown`

The code to update my position:

```
        private async void UpdateMyPosition(Geocoordinate coordinates, bool setView = false)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    MyLocation = new Location()
                    {
                        Latitude = coordinates.Point.Position.Latitude,
                        Longitude = coordinates.Point.Position.Longitude
                    };

                    this.MyPosLayer.Children.Clear();
                    AddPushpin(MyLocation, "", "", this.MyPosLayer, template: this.Resources["MyPositionPushpin"] as ControlTemplate);

                    if (setView)
                    {
                        double zoomLevel = (this.singleRoute == null) ? 14 : 18;

                        if (this.TargetsMap.ZoomLevel < zoomLevel)
                            zoomLevel = TargetsMap.ZoomLevel;

                        TargetsMap.SetView(MyLocation, zoomLevel);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Log.WriteLog(exc.ToString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The error occurs without user interaction on different machines with different hardware.
Unfortunately I cannot catch the exception because it occurs in windows.ui.xaml.dll.
I am using the newest version of the SDK from bing-map.

In the app crash-folder are triagedump.dmp and a memory.hdmp which show the same error.

Has anybody experienced a similar error? Or does anybody have any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Using Bing Maps for Windows 8 Metro Apps - C# / JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408457/Using-Bing-Maps-for-Windows-8-Metro-Apps-Csharp-Ja)